# DHCP server access problem

Tags: dhcp, spanning-tree, vtp

What will stop a PC from receiving an IP address from a DHCP server? Is it STP, VTP, 802.1Q or DTP? What is the most preferable of these?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Hi is your DHCP configuration is on layer3 device or in Active director server or any third-party. If your DHCP pools configured on layer3 switch means onces clear DHCP conflict #clear ip DHCP conflict* This above command we clear if there is any conflict on DHCP allocation If your DHCP is on server check excluded address or check for clearing DHCP conflicts

Answer (score 3):

Neither.

DHCP works by the server receiving the client's broadcast - so you need a working broadcast domain (aka L2 segment aka VLAN) in between, unless you're using a DHCP relay. As long as the network is functioning, DHCP will work.

xSTP, VTP, or DTP all *help* establishing and maintaining a working network. There are no 'most preferable' protocols in these - you use whatever is best in your situation which you haven't detailed. (Except that MSTP is preferable over RSTP which is generally preferable over obsolete classic STP.)